# custom uiSearchBar does not seem to call updateSearchResults

Tags: ios, search, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

In iOS 11 it seems that apple has changed the default height of the UISearchBar to 56px and in an effort to make my app look the same on both ios 11 and < ios 11, i tried creating a custom UISearchBar that would replace the UISearchBar but for some reason when it becomes the first responder the search controllers delegate method updateSearchResults is never called. Can someone help me figure this out.

```
var searchController: CustomSearchController!
func viewDidLoad(){
...
searchController = CustomSearchController(searchResultsController: nil,
                                                   customSearchBar: UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 44.0)))
showsSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
showsSearchController.customSearchBar.delegate = self
```

Comment: Did you find a solution here?